# http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml...... (only in some of the jsp pages of a project)

Tags: xml, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, jstl

I had a problem with '`The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application`'.

My project worked well in the morning and I faced this problem near evening on the same day. Some of my jsp pages have no problem to load but some of them displayed the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:475)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1410)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I have same `taglib` for every of my `jsp` which is:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

and my `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

By the way, I don't have `pom.xml` in my project.

What could possibly go wrong in such a short time? What can I do to solve this? I had sit in front of my computer for hours to find a solution. Please help me. :(

Tomcat version - 7.0.56

jstl-1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by replacing `jstl-1.2` to `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1` (the API) and `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar` (the impl) as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info. Both jar files are available to download  there.

Remember to refresh and clean your project after the new jar files are copied into your WEB-INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

While working on Eclipse although I have added jar files in the build path ( class path) but I forgot to add in Web-INF/lib. So do not do this mistake.

Also, refresh the project so that to load the newly added jars.